# Unable to access Solr web interface running on remote server

Tags: solr, putty, tunnel

We have the SOLR search application running on our both our QA and PROD servers. I'm able to access the web interface for solr on the prod sever by setting up a tunnel to the 8983 port on that server via putty (using local port 48983). However, I'm unable to access the solr interface on the QA server, using local port 18983 - the browser spins, and the message says "waiting for localhost".

I'm using exactly the same technique in for QA as I am for Prod, i.e. using putty to set up a tunnel. The only difference is putty is pointing at a the QA server. The url I'm using is

```
http://localhost:18983/solr/#/~cores/myCore
```

I've validated that solr is running and that it's listening on port 8983 on the QA server.  It works in an application running on the QA server. I've tried changing the local port in putty to the same one used for prod, 48983, but still get the same no-response. The port used by putty, 22, isn't closed - telnetting it receives a response, and anyway I wouldn't be able to log in to the remote system if it wasn't running.

There is security policy on in effect on both QA and PROD that allows all ports and all protocols. I know that's a bad idea, but I'm just trying to solve this issue.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I did what I should've done in the first place and saved a copy of the Prod putty to a separate copy for the QA, then modified that to access QA. Sure enough, it worked. I don't know what the actual problem was, unfortunately.